# Make Dyalog APL Language bar bigger

Tags: user-interface, ide, font-size, apl, dyalog

How to make button size of Language bar bigger in Dyalog APL version 18.0[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right-click on any of the symbols, then select "Use the Session font". The language bar will now use the same font size as the main input/output area. You can adjust this size using the font size selector in the toolbar:

[image: screenshot]